# Repositories.cfg could not be loaded

Tags: android, angularjs, android-studio, ionic

Estoy tratando de compilar una aplicacion para android usando el siguiente comando, `ionic build android` para Ionic 1.x, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
File C:\Users\User\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
```

La información d mi equipo es:

- SO: Windows 10 32 Bits
- Node: 6.10.1
- Ionic: 2.2.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Debería crearte un archivo `repositories.cfg` automáticamente:

Si existe, eliminalo o elimina su contenido y reinicia Android Studio.

Si no existe te recomiendo crear un archivo sin contenido `repositories.cfg` en el path:

```
C:\Users\User\.android\
```

Comment: Ya estoy probando, voy a compilar y te comento

Comment: ya no sale el error, salio un error alli, pero es de otra cosa, voy a solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: Perfecto Pedro.  Saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ